# FacesContext message after exception is thrown

Tags: java, jsf, exception, jsf-2, primefaces

i have a try/catch block, in the catch i send a message, something about the problem then i throw the exception (to block everything that comes after, in this case, i'm in the business rule method, i want to avoid everything in the managed bean method)

Well, if i only send the message it works ok but doesn't block the calling method (the method that called the one who has the actual trycatch)

What i actually have:

```
public void save() {
    ProdEN prod;
    if(prod.getId() == null) {
        prod = prodDB.insert(prod);
    } else {
        prod = prodDB.update(prod);
    }
    if(prod== null) {
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage(MessageProvider.getMessage("error.save"));
    }
    FacesUtil.addInfoMessage(MessageProvider.getMessage("products.save.success"));
}
```

and then, the method that was called:

```
public ProdEN insert(ProdEN prod) {
    try {
        beginTransaction();
        prod = (ProdEN) insert(prod, true);
        commitTransaction();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage(MessageProvider.getMessage("error.save"));
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        throw ex;
    }
    return prod;
}
```

Tried some search and all i found didn't work, any ideas? thanks.

Comment: I think in java you can't define object with name return. **ProdEN return;** there should be error.

Comment: aw sorry that was a copypaste error while pasting here :p

Answer (score 1):

It should work like this.

**Changes to your insert method.**

You don't need to add error message here. Also you don't need to return the prod object. Java changes it value value.

```
public void insert(ProdEN prod) {
    try {
        beginTransaction();
        prod = (ProdEN) insert(prod, true);
        commitTransaction();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //FacesUtil.addErrorMessage(MessageProvider.getMessage("error.save"));
        //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        throw ex;
    }
    //return prod;
}
```

**And now your save method.**

```
public void save() {
    ProdEN prod;
    try{
          if(prod.getId() == null) {
               prodDB.insert(prod);
               if(prod.getId()==null){
                FacesUtil.addErrorMessage(MessageProvider.getMessage("error.save"));
                return
               }
           } else {
              prod = prodDB.update(prod);
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
    FacesUtil.addErrorMessage(MessageProvider.getMessage("error.save"));
    return;
    }

    FacesUtil.addInfoMessage(MessageProvider.getMessage("products.save.success"));
}
```

Comment: `if(prod.getId() == null)` inside `if(prod.getId() == null)` does not make any sense. Remove it, please. You don't need `else` case when if contains return. `;` missing after first return.

Comment: @VasilLukach The reason OP put that so if the id is null then insert it. The insert operation should update the id ,so it is checking after the insert that did the ID was populated or not.

Comment: i was trying to do something like a custom exception, to throw an exception and also add it to faces message, i mean like this: throw `new CustomException("my.message.resource");` but when i do this, it cancel everything, it looks like it cancel the message production and don't show in the view, idk how to fix it..